# Write the complex function |cos(z)| in the form a+ib if z=3-i

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I put 
$ |cos z| = ((e^{iz} + e^{-iz})/2)^2$
and solved it to get 
$1/4( e^{6i}. e^2 +e^{-2} . e^{-6i} +2^8.2^{-6i})$
I know i can write the exponential term in form of cos and sin but how do I solve $2^{-6i}$?

Comment: Use e^{expression} instead of e^expression.. The latter will only exponentiate the first symbol of your expression.

Comment: Your expression for $\;|\cos z|\;$ seems to be wrong: on the right side you simply have $\;\cos^2z\;$ , not $\;|\cos z|\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\;z=x+iy\;$ :

$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2=\frac{e^{ix-y}+e^{-ix+y}}2=\frac{\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)\cos x-i\left(e^y-e^{-y}\right)\sin x}2\implies $$

$$|\cos z|=\sqrt{\cosh^2y\cos^2x+\sinh^2y\sin^2x}\stackrel{x=3\,,\,y=-1}=\sqrt{\cosh^2(-1)\cos^23+\sinh^2(-1)\sin^23}$$

Comment: So the answer contains only real part?

Comment: @Maya Of course. For any complex $\;z=x+iy\;$ , we have that $\;|z|=|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;$ The modulus (or absolute value, as you prefer) of any complex number is always a non-negative real number.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{-i}=\cos(\log a)-i\sin(\log a)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use that, when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

1. $$e^{\text{z}i}=e^{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)i}=e^{\Re\left[\text{z}\right]i-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}=e^{-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot e^{\Re\left[\text{z}\right]i}=e^{-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot\left(\cos\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)+\sin\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)i\right)$$
2. $$e^{-\text{z}i}=e^{-\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)i}=e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]-\Re\left[\text{z}\right]i}=e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot e^{-\Re\left[\text{z}\right]i}=e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot\left(\cos\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)-\sin\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)i\right)$$
3. $$\cos\left(\text{z}\right)=\frac{e^{\text{z}i}+e^{-\text{z}i}}{2}$$
4. $$\left|\cos\left(\text{z}\right)\right|=\left|\frac{e^{\text{z}i}+e^{-\text{z}i}}{2}\right|=\frac{\left|e^{\text{z}i}+e^{-\text{z}i}\right|}{\left|2\right|}=\frac{\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[e^{\text{z}i}\right]+\Re\left[e^{-\text{z}i}\right]\right)^2+\left(\Im\left[e^{\text{z}i}\right]+\Im\left[e^{-\text{z}i}\right]\right)^2}}{2}$$
5. $$\Re\left[e^{\text{z}i}\right]+\Re\left[e^{-\text{z}i}\right]=e^{-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot\cos\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)+e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot\cos\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)=\cos\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)\cdot\left(e^{-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}+e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\right)$$
6. $$\Im\left[e^{\text{z}i}\right]+\Im\left[e^{-\text{z}i}\right]=e^{-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot\sin\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)-e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot\sin\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)=\sin\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)\cdot\left(e^{-\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}-e^{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}\right)$$

So:

$$\left|\cos\left(\text{z}\right)\right|=\frac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)+\cosh\left(2\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}$$